# How to force audio not being delayed compared to video while processing ffmpeg filters?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, sync

I apply zoom filter on a 2k video but I've noticed the audio doesn't go with it. It's slightly delayed. I guess it's an issue with my cpu or gpu because there are lot of processing.

```
ffmpeg -i e:/vid.mp4 -vf "scale=1920*2:1080*2,zoompan=z='min(max(zoom,pzoom)+0.001,5)':x='iw/(1/0.5)-(iw/zoom/(1/0.5))':y='ih/(1/0.33)-(ih/zoom/(1/0.33))':d=1,scale=1280:720,fps=30000/1001" -b:v 1000k e:/vid+.mp4
```

My question is: are there any helping methods to overcome this? I already lowered output scale and input multiplier from 3 to 2. Can I simply force synchronize this with some parameters??

To be more precise the effect looks in this way: input video is 1:47 long, output is 2:08, audio is not changed. I added `fps` variable but it didn't help.

**EDIT**

I've found workaround but this shouldn't work that way. Just speed up that delayed video after conversion about factor of "107.37/128.5", what is the audio duration to video duration and then reapplied audio to the new video.

Comment: What is the expected outcome? For the video to stay at `1:47` or for the audio to be somehow adjusted to be `2:08`?

Comment: @Destroy666 Video is lagged - it should be as audio, which is normal.

Comment: And the input video is 30FPS?

Comment: @Destroy666 Yes, to be precise fps=30000/1001. Output shows it's the same, but video is slower.

Comment: how about leaving away the fps parameter from the output? that way it should correspond to the input.